# Closing a resource stored in Option[ ]

Tags: scala, resources, resource-management

I have a resource object stored in an option.

```
 private var ochan: Option[Channel] = None
```

At some point during program execution, `ochan` is set to `Some(channel)`. I'd like to close the channel (via invoking the method `close`) and set the option to `None` in one fatal swoop.

Currently I have:

```
 def disconnect = ochan = { ochan.foreach{_.close}; None }
```

And previously I had:

```
 def disconnect = ochan = ochan.flatMap{ o => o.close; None }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should clarify what does "better" mean for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
def disconnect = ochan = ochan match {
  case Some(ch) => ch.close(); None
  case None => None // do nothing
}
```

instead of using `foreach` or `flatMap`. In my opinion, this solution shows more clearly and explicitly what happens. The solution with `foreach` or `flatMap` requires an extra mental jump, you'd have to know what these methods do on an `Option`.

Comment: I agree with the mental jump issue with foreach and flatMap.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that it's better but it's shorter (once you've defined the implicit):

```
implicit def closer(o: Option[Channel]) = new { 
  def close(): Option[Channel] = { o.foreach(_.close); None } 
}

def disconnect = ochan = ochan.close
```

Comment: Writing a second function which duplicates the first function in order to simplify the first function seems more complex to me ... and less readable.

Comment: @Anonymous If that's an issue then you simply add synchronization. I don't think this is an issue in practice, you'd most likely not use the same channel object from multiple threads at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no big difference between an immutable var and a mutable val. So why not encapsulate the behavior in a separate class, when you want to have mutability anyway?

```
class ChannelOption {
  private var _channel :Option[Channel] = None
  def channel = _channel
  def channel_=(ch:Option[Channel]) { _channel.foreach(_.close); _channel = ch }
}
```

Usage:

```
private val ochan = new ChannelOption
ochan.channel = Some(getAChannel)
ochan.channel.foreach(useChannel)
ochan.channel = Some(getAnotherChannel) //this automatically closes the first channel
ochan.channel = None //this automatically closes the second channel
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not thread safe! Remember to use @volatile (not here; using synchronization), and do something like this: (this is why I don't like imperative code)

```
private val lock = new Object

def disconnect() {//Function has side effects: remember parenthesis!
  lock.synchronized { //Synchronizations is important; you don't want to close it multiple times
    ochan.foreach {_.close()} //Again: side effects -> parens.
  }
}
```

And if you don't use parallel programming, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `ochan_=` so that assigning a new value to `ochan` closes the old channel (similar to `std::auto_ptr<>` in C++) but I don't see how you can encapsulate that in a child class of `Option[Channel]` because the storage is in your class.  The solution wouldn't change the code much at all, it would just make `disconnect` implicit by assigning `ochan`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could work:

```
def disconnect { 
  ochan = {
    ochan.get.close
    None
  }
}
```

or

```
def disconnect {
  ochan.get.close
  ochan = None
}
```

Anyway since there is mutating operation, it will always need 2 calls (1 for close and one for assignment of None).

Comment: Don't use the `get` method, it's not typesafe.

Comment: @Jesper Nordenberg I think it's still "typesafe", perhaps "not None-safe"? (`val x: Option[String] = None; x.get` -- compiles fine, runs not-so-much)

Comment: `get` will throw a runtime exception when called on `None`, making it compile time type unsafe.

Comment: @Jesper Nordenberg See above. It is still [typesafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). `null.asInstanceOf[String].length` is arguably typesafe (although perhaps I am pushing the boundary here with `asInstanceOf`? the previous comment was well in the bounds of typesafety as I understand it, though)

Comment: @Jesper Nordenberg Consider `val someOption = getUnknownOption(); someOption.get` as being similar to `val y: Int = getUnknown(); val z = 1 / y` (where whether `someOption` is Some/None or `y` is 0/non-0 is not known)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact definition of "typesafe" that you are using, but to quote the text you linked to _In the context of static (compile-time) type systems, type safety usually involves (among other things) a guarantee that the eventual value of any expression will be a legitimate member of that expression's static type._. A runtime exception is certainly not a member of the type Option[T], so I will continue to call `get` type unsafe (for a lack of a better term).